# Why is this mysql connection failing?

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

I am having an interesting problem with php and mysql.

I am trying to write a simple connect and query script to mysql on my localhost(same host as webserver) and am having some problems retrieving data, also anything that is below the php code disappears when you do a view source on the web site.

I am running apache2, I have installed php5 and other php commands work like echo.

Here is the php code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass"); // corrected mysql spellings
  if(!$con)
    {
      die('could not connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

  mysql_select_db("db", $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_list");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['name'] . "<br />";
  }

  mysql_close($con);


  echo "hello";

?>

trying testing
</body>

</html>
```

Please  let me know if there is anything I should check to see if my server setup is correct.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: checking spellings and other trivial things before posting questions will safe time for both of us :)

Comment: Yep, will do next time. Problem still stand though :(

Comment: What error do you get???

Comment: No error, just a blank page. andyinsandiego.com/sql_connect.php for reference.

Comment: Try using this at top of the page `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
and then see if it shows any error?

Comment: Did a server restart and now it works. hmm. might have been the misspelling then! thanks everyone, glad I learned about the error reporting as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written `mysl_connect` instead of `mysql_connect` on line 8.

If you had error reporting turned on (which you should do only for development), you would have seen an error message telling you about this.

Comment: Yikes how embarrassing, unfortunately after correction the error hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this way ?

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die ("Error connection");
mysql_select_db($nameBDD) or die ("Error BDD");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query)))
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure that your error_reporting is at E_ALL | E_STRICT in your php.ini ?
Secondly, add a `or die(mysql_error())` after the mysql_select_db